# How to delete an object in local webstorage with a button

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a school project and I need to make a music website, it's almost finished, but I'm having problems doing the playlist with web local storage.

```js
'use strict'

const configs = {
  PLAYLIST_KEY: "playlist",
};

function addMusicToPlaylist(data) {
  let musics = new Array();

  if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(configs.PLAYLIST_KEY)) {
    musics = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(configs.PLAYLIST_KEY));
  }

  musics.push(data);

  localStorage.setItem(configs.PLAYLIST_KEY, JSON.stringify(musics));
}

$(".add-music-button").on("click", function () {
  let musicRef = $(this).data("ref");

  let musicObject = {
    author: $(`#${musicRef} .music-author`).html(),
    title: $(`#${musicRef} .music-title`).html(),
  };

  addMusicToPlaylist(musicObject);
});

$(document).ready(function () {

  if ($("#playlist-table").length > 0) {
    if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(configs.PLAYLIST_KEY)) { // testa se o objecto tem a propriedade especificada

      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(configs.PLAYLIST_KEY)).map(
        (music, index) => {
          $("#playlist-table").append(`
          <tr id="music-${index}">
            <td class="music-author">${music.author}</td>
            <td class="music-title">${music.title}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td><p class="textoFav"></p></td> musica<td><button class="favBotao" onclick="apagar()" ><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button></td></tr>
        `);
        }
      );
    }
  }
});

function apagar (){
    localStorage.removeItem('playlist')
}
```

I only can remove all of the musics inside the playlist, but i want to remove only one music, like this:

"button 1 : music 1

button 2 : music 2

button 3 : music 3

button 4 : music 4"

If the user presses button 3, I want it to delete from the playlist, the music 3.
How can I do that?

Comment: You should `setItem(musics)` where musics is array of elements without one that you wish to delete - you must update local storage item content, not delete it completely.

Comment: Don't think about it as "the music in local storage"; think about it as an array of items. How do you delete an item from an array? [`slice`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5767325/215552). Once you have the array the way you want it, serialize and store it in local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an index argument, i.e: `onclick="apagar(index)"`.

Then, create `apagar` function:

```
function apagar(index) {
   let musics = new Array();
   musics = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(configs.PLAYLIST_KEY));

   musics = musics.filter((_, i) => i !== index);

   localStorage.setItem(configs.PLAYLIST_KEY, JSON.stringify(musics));
}
```

Comment: if i set and index argument in "onclick = "apagar(index)" gives me and error saying :" index is not defined

Comment: Use string interpolation: `apagar(${ index })`